# How to send data to client browsers when a server side change occurs

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, server-side, crm

I have an intranet based CRM application developed in CodeIgniter 2.1 where the application is running on a local Apache server and around 20 clients are accessing it over LAN. This is to be connected to a call center setup where the call center application (running on a separate server) will do a HTTP post with caller's number as well as terminal number of the agent where the call is arriving to a URL of my Codeigniter application. I am using this data to populate a database table of call records.

Now from the terminal number (each terminal has static IP, and a session in Codeigniter is linked to IP as well) I can find out which user (login session) of my application is about to receive the call. **I want to find a way out how I can send data from server side** (it will be regarding the call like the number who is calling, past call records etc.) **to that specific user's browser** via AJAX or something similar? The agent's browser needs to display this information sent from server.
Periodic polling from browser by jquery etc. is not possible as the data needs to be updated almost instantaneously and rapid polling up to this extent will lead to high CPU usage at client end as well as extra load on network.

P.S.: I only want to know how to modify the browser data from server end.

Answer (score 1):

In AJAX, asynchronous request/response doesn't involve polling; there's just an open TCP connection and non-blocking I/O.  The client makes a request but returns immediately; when the server sends the response, the client is notified. So you can achieve what you want with AJAX's XMLHttpRequest without polling[1].  All you need is a url from which to serve your notifications.  You could have one request thread and a general dispatch method, or different urls and different threads for each, depending on how you needed to scale.

[1] Well, to be honest, with *very little* polling.  You'd really need to establish what the session/global timeout was and reissue requests within that time limit.